# Ubuntu server om Raspberry pi 4 and laravel problem

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, raspberry-pi4

I have a working Ubuntu server 20.04 on the Raspberry 4 and have this virtual site working written in HTML and PHP: http://temperatur.gleeze.com DDNS through dynu.com. But if I make a simple Laravel site all I am getting is this error:
"Service Unavailable
The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.
Additionally, a 503 Service Unavailable error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request."
Any Laravel site gets this error on the server. But that site works fine on localhost.
What can be wrong?

Comment: Ask this on [sf], I think you will get help faster

Answer (score 0):

I was creating a 32 bit Ubuntu. After reinstall with 64 bit Ubuntu all works perfect.